# <MenuItems /> is missing a parent <Menu /> component error (with MenuItems in slot)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, headless-ui

I am creating a component in Vue3 called <**Dropdown**>.

The **Dropdown** component uses other components in turn: **Menu, MenuItems, MenuItem and MenuButton** from the **headlessui/vue library**.

My idea is that you can put any content in the **Dropdown**, that's why I created a slot called *#contentdropdown*.

The problem is that when I pass this slot content to the Dropdown component, Vue gives me the following error:

**< MenuItems /> is missing a parent < Menu /> component**

This is my Dropdown componente code:

```
<template>
  <Menu as="div" class="relative inline-block text-left">
    <div>
      <MenuButton class="btn inline-flex justify-center w-full text-sm" :class="'btn-'+variant">
        Options
        <ChevronDownIcon class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
      </MenuButton>
    </div>

    <transition enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100" enter-from-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95" enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100" leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75" leave-from-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100" leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95">
      <slot name="contentdropdown"></slot>
    </transition>
  </Menu>
</template>

<script>
import { Menu, MenuButton } from '@headlessui/vue'
import { ChevronDownIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/solid'
import { vVariantProp } from '../../../../constants'
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue';

export default {

    name: 'dropdown',

    props: {
  
        ...vVariantProp,
    },

    setup(props) {

        props = reactive(props);
    
        return {
           
        }
    },
    
};
</script>
```

Why does it need the parent component called Menu?, if in fact I am already painting the slot inside the  component and also importing it inside the Dropdown component.

This is how I pass to the Dropdown component the content through its #contentdropdown slot:

```
<Dropdown v-bind="{'variant':'primary'}">
          <template #contentdropdown>
            <MenuItems class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
              <div class="py-1">
                <MenuItem>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm">Subitem1</a>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm">Subitem2</a>
                </MenuItem>
              </div>
            </MenuItems>
          </template>
        </Dropdown>
```

Comment: Did you try it without Transition? Could be specific to how it works

Comment: The result and error is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The error `<MenuItems /> is missing a parent <Menu /> component` is not a Vue specific error. It is an error thrown by `headlessui/vue` - [source](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/blob/6253aa52b3801e84331450a651bb41328ffa7239/packages/%40headlessui-vue/src/components/menu/menu.ts#L73)

`MenuItems` component (as well as `MenuButon`  etc - see [doc](https://headlessui.com/vue/menu#menu-items)) is designed to be used inside `Menu` component. It is using `inject` to tap into state [provideded](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#provide) by the `Menu` component. There is nothing you can do about it - it is designed that way

Problem is that slot content (everything inside `<template #contentdropdown>` in the last code example) in Vue is always rendered in [parent scope](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#render-scope)

> Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope; everything in the child template is compiled in the child scope.

This means that `MenuItems` rendered as slot content has no access to data `provide`ded by the `Menu` component rendered inside your `Dropdown` component

I don't see any way to overcome this limitation. You'll need to change your design (or describe your use case to `headlessui/vue` maintainers and ask them to implement alternative approach to share [MenuContext](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/blob/6253aa52b3801e84331450a651bb41328ffa7239/packages/%40headlessui-vue/src/components/menu/menu.ts#L218) with child components - for example using slot props)